# Header redirect not refreshing redirect page

Tags: php, redirect

I have a login form embedded in the sidebar of my page.
Once the user logs in using it, I want it to redirect back to the same page they logged in from.

Which is easy enough to achieve. However when the login function completes and redirects to the original page but it isn't actually refreshing it. The login form changes from a form to a user info display. Despite the user actually now being logged in it still displays the login form.

I have tried using the

```
header ( "refresh:0;url=url.php" );
```

However I cannot get the URL the user has come from to resolve properly and redirect to it.

The code I am using is below

```
if( isset( $_POST['location'] ) ) {
    $location = htmlspecialchars($_POST['location']);
    header( "Location:" .HOME_PATH. urlencode($location) );
}
```

Is there a simple way to force the refresh or is it best to use something like AJAX to achieve the same thing.

I'm thinking the simplest thing is to use the refresh header however I don't understand how to achieve the same effect as I have used in the Location.

**EDIT:**

The login form checks to see if the user is logged in and changes to a display instead of login form if they aren't.

```
<?php if ( isset( $_SESSION['userName'] ) ) { ?>
```

The form then posts to a php function. The function actually carries out the logging in of the user, and once this is done it redirects to the page they came from. This is where the problem lies. The return redirect **doesn't** refresh the page so the form condition can change what is being displayed.

Comment: is your code that displays the login form correctly checking to see if the user is logged in?

Comment: yes it is `<?php if ( isset( $_SESSION['userName'] ) ) { ?>`

Comment: You can check if whether the user is logged in or not before displaying the form or the info.

Comment: I have that built it into the function, however if the user is logged in they won't be able to see the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`header("Location: ...")` won't stop the rendering of the page. You need to halt by placing an `exit` right after it.

Comment: It does redirect successfully it just doesn't refresh the page to show that the user is now logged in and so change the form. I have tried using `exit;` and it doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: Yes, maybe it does but still now it's a the proper way to use a redirect, you should always terminate the execution of the page using `exit` or `die`, right after redirect, otherwise there is a chance to show the page temporarily for a while before browser redirects to different location.

Comment: @user1711576, forget the redirect, just check every time whether the user is logged in or not, right before you output the form part and display items according to the loggedin state.

Comment: I do, do that however the page doesn't refresh for the php to check if the user is now logged in